# Why does a new local branch immediately start tracking the local branch it was created from and how do I turn this off?

Tags: git, github, git-branch

I have a very strange problem. Whenever I create a new branch, that new branch starts tracking the branch it was created from. For example, if I'm on the `main` branch and create a `new` branch, `new` immediately starts tracking the `master` branch. I literally get the message `branch 'new' set up to track 'master'`. If I create another branch `anotherBranch` it will immediately be set to track either `main` or `new` depending which branch it was created from. Switching, for example to `new`, I'm getting a message like `Your branch is behind 'main' by 1 commit, and can be fast forwarded.` or something like that (I mean, it behaves the same as I have a track between the local branch and correspondent remote branch). Does anyone know why this is happening and how to fix it?

It started happening all of a sudden, not before... I even tried reinstalling Git, but unfortunately it didn't work.

Comment: You can't turn it off. You can create branches from whichever point you like, though

Comment: @evolutionxbox Yes, I know that, but the problem is that my new branch starts tracing the branch it was created from and that's not normal behavior (I guess not, it didn't happen to me before). That's the problem here.

Comment: Trace or track?

Comment: @evolutionxbox Well it says `track`. Sorry for the wrong wording. I will correct it now, but the problem is same.

Comment: You might be using aliases.

Comment: Have you recently changed the `branch.autoSetupMerge` git config variable?

Comment: Please may you share the output of `git config --global --list`?

Comment: @Roman I don't know if something changed by accident. There could potentially be a problem. What should I do to get it back to "normal" behavior and shouldn't it just come back when reinstalling git?

Comment: @evolutionxbox 
user.email=-@gmail.com
user.name=-
core.editor="C:\Users\filip\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code\bin\code" --wait
gui.recentrepo=D:/exercise/Patronus
branch.autosetupmerge=always

Comment: Hmmm. Please may you also share the output of `git remote -v`? It could be that the remote is the current repo?

Comment: You can unset the variable, so it will use the default. Reinstalling git probably doesn't wipe the config.

Comment: @evolutionxbox It's totally new local repository (I just made it for this question but it happens in all my repos...), so `git remote -v` does not give any output.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have `branch.autoSetupMerge` git config variable set to `always`. To quote [the manual](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-config#Documentation/git-config.txt-branchautoSetupMerge):

> `always` — automatic setup is done when the starting point is either a local branch or remote-tracking branch
>
> [...]
>
> This option defaults to true.

So you can unset it and git will use the default:

```
git config --unset branch.autoSetupMerge
```

(maybe you'll need to add the `--global` or other file-selecting option).

Comment: Thank you. Yes, I need to add it globally, so `git config --global --unset branch.autoSetupMerge` solved my problem completely. All best!